# Outlook365 - Inbox rules: How to do "Subject BEGINS WITH these words...."

Tags: microsoft-outlook, office365

I am using rules more and more do handle all the automated emails that come my way.

But without a "begins with" option, rules are, in some cases, either:

- not possible
  or
- too broad, and will trash emails that need to be seen

How to resolve?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Sorry, you can't. There are no "begins with", "ends with", etc. conditions in Outlook rules.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, that feature has been available in competent email clients since 1994, so Microsoft needed to remove it due to age.

Comment: Not sure if that answers the question

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1140587)